# PHP - Using asterisk symbol in file path

Tags: php, filenames, asterisk

I have an image with today's date and a title (which is the image's actual name), and I'm trying to get PHP to find any file in the directory beginning with today's date. I tried this:

HTML

```
<img src="<?php
$imgDate = date("Y-m-d");
echo "path/".$imgDate."_*.*";
?>" />
```

This is supposed to insert today's date (2015-04-15) and an underscore (_) along with anything that begins with them using he asterisk (*). The (*) is supposed to find **ANY** file with a file name beginning with `2015-04-15_`and **ANY** extension, to allow for image files such as JPG or GIF.

I looked everywhere online for a solution but couldn't find one. Not even in Stack Overflow.

If there is a better way, or the code I showed you makes ABSOLUTELY no sense, please let me know what it is. I'm working on a website blog that I can easily post things on. If I can figure out this problem, I can figure out the other details.

This is my first time posting a question in Stack Overflow, so forgive me for my lack of details (or PHP ignorance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `glob()` function like this:

```
$matches = glob("path/".$imgDate."_*.*");
```

You should get an array of all matching files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: It still doesn't work. The image is not showing, and no error message is shown. If I were to get rid of the asterisk and the underscore, then change the filename to 2015-04-16.png, it works. But, I want the title so I can know which image it is.

Comment: WAIT! Your link to the glob() manual helped me out. I did `foreach (glob("path/".imgDate."*.*") as $imgFile){ echo "$imgFile"; }` and it worked perfectly! Thanks for you help. ^u^

Comment: It's great if that works for you in this case but be aware that `glob()` returns _file_ paths, not _url_ paths. In the future, you may encounter situations where that distinction is important.